# java error exception in thread "main" java.util.illegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java

my code compiles but when i try to run it, an error message says there is an exception at main java.util.illegalFormatConversionException. how can i fix this? i am sure i got the placeholders right for each variable?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BookTest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    double charge;
    double totalCharge=0;
    double totalTax=0;
    double grandTotal=0;

    String dataArray[][] = {{"NonFiction", "Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter","Grahame-Smith","978-0446563079","13.99","Haper","NY","US","Political"},
          {"NonFiction", "Frankenstein","Shelley","978-0486282114","7.99","Pearson", "TX","England", "Historical"},
          {"Fiction", "Dracula","Stoker","978-0486411095","5.99","Double Day", "CA","4918362"},
          {"NonFiction", "Curse of the Wolfman"," Hageman","B00381AKHG","10.59","Harper", "NY","Transylvania","Historical"},
          {"Fiction", "The Mummy","Rice","978-0345369949","7.99","Nelson","GA","3879158"}};

    Book bookArray[] = new Book[dataArray.length];

    int quantityArray[] = {12, 3, 7, 23, 5};


    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
    {
      if (dataArray[i][0].equals("NonFiction"))
      {
        bookArray[i] = new NonFictionBook(dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3], Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]),
        new Publisher(dataArray[i][5], dataArray[i][6]), dataArray[i][7], dataArray[i][8]);
      }
      else
      {
        bookArray[i] = new FictionBook(dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][3], Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][4]),
        new Publisher(dataArray[i][5], dataArray[i][6]), Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i][7]));
      }
    }

    String msg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++)
    {
      charge = bookArray[i].calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]);
      totalTax = bookArray[i].calculateTax(bookArray[i].calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]));

      totalCharge = charge + totalCharge;
      grandTotal = totalCharge + totalTax; 

      if (bookArray[i] instanceof FictionBook)
      {
        FictionBook fb = (FictionBook)bookArray[i];
        msg += String.format("%s  %d  $%.2f  $%.2f\n", fb.getTitle(), fb.getCode(), charge, fb.calculateTax(fb.calculateTotal(quantityArray[i])));  
      }

      if (bookArray[i] instanceof NonFictionBook)
      {
        NonFictionBook nfb = (NonFictionBook)bookArray[i];
        msg += String.format("%s  %s  $%.2f  $%.2f\n", nfb.getTitle(), nfb.getCategory(), charge, nfb.calculateTax(nfb.calculateTotal(quantityArray[i])));
      } 
    }
    // ––– this is where the error is at
    msg += String.format("Total $%.2f", "Total Tax $%.2f", "Grand Total $%.2f",  totalCharge, totalTax, grandTotal);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be of exponential help to us if you could state which line of code was causing the problem..

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Answer (score 1):

Look at this call - I've put the arguments on different lines:

```
String.format(
    "Total $%.2f",
    "Total Tax $%.2f",
    "Grand Total $%.2f",
    totalCharge,
    totalTax,
    grandTotal)
```

That's passing `"Total $%.2f"` as the format string, and then five values to be formatted within that string - the first of which is *itself* a string, but you're trying to format it *as a float*. I suspect you really wanted something like:

```
String.format(
    "Total $%.2f%nTotal Tax $%.2f%nGrand Total $%.2f",
    totalCharge,
    totalTax,
    grandTotal)
```

Here we've got a format string with three placeholders, and then three values to format - which makes a lot more sense. The `%n` within the format string represents a new line.

If that *isn't* what you wanted, you should be clearer about what you *expected* the broken code to do...

Comment: yes it worked thanks i will remember that for next time

Answer (score 0):

Check the quotation marks.

You are trying to format `"Total $%.2f"` with `"Total Tax $%.2f"`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't delete answer in app. Will give from desktop later.

Answer (score 0):

Your line must looks like:

```
 msg += String.format("Total $%.2f, Total Tax $%.2f, Grand Total $%.2f",  totalCharge, totalTax, grandTotal); //this is where the error is at
```

remove the doublequotes inside the string.